# Is "Could you help me move these boxes?" interpreted as deontic or dynamic when it comes to the modality families?

Tags: modal-verbs, can-could, deontic-vs-epistemic, modality

I have a problem with the following clause:

> Could you help me move these boxes?

I would like to know for my upcoming English test that if this clause is interpreted as epistemic, deontic or dynamic.

I know that if someone is asking for permission then it would be interpreted as deontic, and if we are talking about someone's willingness to help then it would be dynamic as in "I have asked him to help us but he won't."

So how can I know if this interrogative clause is deontic or dynamic because somebody is asking not permission, but someone's willingness to help?

Comment: Didn't you say that *deontic* is asking permission, which this question doesn't?

Comment: The three categories of modals are Epistemic (relating to speculation), Deontic (relating to ideals or regulations), and Dynamic (relating to performance).

Comment: Permission makes no sense. You ask for permission to do something yourself, not for someone else to do something for you. "Could I" can be a permission request, "could you" never is.

Comment: The two possible meanings of "could you" are about ability ("are you able to ...?") or willingness ("Would you like to ...?"). In this particular instance, it's almost always about willingness, and it's implicitly a request for the help (it's considered more polite than saying "Please help me...").

Comment: What @Barmar said. Without further context, *could you help* is a polite form of *will you help* — are you willing to help?

Comment: "Could you" might be deontic in a few cases e.g. to teacher "Could you help me with this question or is it against the rules for you to give help?" But, assuming there's no rule against the person you ask moving boxes, not here.

Comment: You wrote, "if we are talking about someone's willingness to help then it would be dynamic", and then you wrote, "somebody is asking . . . someone's willingness to help". Doesn't that obviously make it dynamic by your own definition, then?

Comment: As 'Could you help me move these boxes?/.' is a polite request (more polite with the questioning tone and an added 'please') equivalent to 'I'd like you to help me ...', I'd say this usage is more politeness-marker than modality based. 'Are you going to help me move these boxes, Tim?' is almost equivalent (if said in a bright, breezy tone), involves modality (volition), but no 'modal verb'.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about a situation in which you're using this question to ask someone else to help you.

According to Huddleston & Pullum (2002), such questions are requests, indirectly conveyed by asking about someone's *ability* to do something. This is because "a likely reason for me to be interested  in your ability to do something is that I want you to do it" (ch. 10, p. 940).

Since the question is thus directly asking about your abilities (rather than about what is deontically permissible), this is a case of dynamic, rather than deontic, modality.